# Fetching intersection on self from a table

Tags: mysql

I have the following (simplified) table:

```
structure_id | hash_id
1              1
1              2
1              3
2              4
2              5
2              1
3              6
3              1
3              4
```

And I want to get the intersection of repeated hash ids as a result - which means  the following for this example:

```
- 1 2 3
1 3 1 1
2 1 3 2
3 1 2 3
```

Because 1 and 1 structure IDs share 3 records, 1 and 2 share 1 record, etc. SQL result would be:

```
id | intersected_id | count
1    1                3
1    2                1
1    3                1
2    1                1
2    2                3
2    3                2
3    1                1
3    2                2
3    3                3
```

It's worth mentioning that the table has about 500mln records, so the query must be as optimized as possible. How can I do that?

What I tried so far is self join:

```
SELECT t1.structure_id, COUNT(t1.hash_id) FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.structure_id != t2.strucutre_id AND t1.hash_id = t2.hash_id GROUP BY t1.structure_id;
```

But it doesn't work correctly - it finds repeated rows in all other structure ids.

Comment: if no one answers soon enough create a sqlfiddle. Not much to ask for

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8945/3 - @Drew - feel free to use this

Comment: thx @zedfoxus, still trying to understand the question. Nice answer a few hrs ago. Never got back to vote it up :)

Comment: Is it really necessary to do it with SQL? It looks easier to just write a program that reads all the records and performs the calculations. This way you have more control over the algorithm, so you can make it reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a self join:

```
select t1.structure_id, t2.structure_id, count(*)
from test t1 join
     test t2
     on t1.hash_id = t2.hash_id
group by t1.structure_id, t2.structure_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I doubt it will be efficient enough for your needs. As I said in a comment, maybe an imperative program would be better suited to that problem.

```
SELECT id 
      ,intersected_id 
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT hash_id) AS `count`
FROM (
  SELECT t1.structure_id AS id 
        ,t2.structure_id AS intersected_id 
        ,t1.hash_id 
  FROM test AS t1
  INNER JOIN test AS t2
  ON t1.hash_id = t2.hash_id
) derived
GROUP BY id, intersected_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8945/6/0)